# Foreach inserting multiple values in database from nth array

Tags: php

I am trying to insert the following data into database from an array in the nth(this case 3rd inner) array. The `$bigDataArray` contains two more arrays but we're interested with the last(3rd) array in it. The `$requiredArray` returns so many records and has many fields. I wish to just select a few fields and insert all the values associated with them to a database. It should also be noted that am **not** fetching this data from a mysql database since we're just provided with the data in that form. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

```
foreach ($bigDataArray->getAll() as $requiredArray) {
             foreach ($requiredArray as $cols => $records) { 
             // just pick the required data for analysis
                    if($cols == "xx1" || $cols == "xx2" || $cols == "xx4" || $cols == "xxn"){

                     // I want insert $cols as fields and $row as records in database,then just update values in xx2 if xx1 already exists

                    }
               }      
            }
```

the `print_r($requiredArray)`
`y\ac\r\Response Object
(
    [unrecognized:protected] => Array
        (
        )

```
[_type:y\ac\r\Response:private] => !re
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [.id] => 3
        [name] => Kelvin
        [target] => b.b.bb.g
        [parent] => none
        [rpap] => 
        [rpip] => 8/8
        [defval] => default-small/default-small
        [l-at] => 512000/1000000
        [m-it] => 512000/2000000
        [b-l] => 0/0
        [b-ld] => 0/0
        [b-ti] => 0s/0s
        [ck-s] => 0.1/0.1
        [activity] => 1645827604/17691224739
        [tbs] => 0
        [pts] => 11900213/13011698
        [tkets] => 0
        [loss] => 98154/2662855
        [t-loss] => 0
        [avg-r] => 70064/2025768
        [p-rate] => 155/172
        [tpt-rate] => 0
        [qets] => 0/4
        [tets] => 0
        [qutes] => 0/5968
        [ttes] => 0
        [inv] => false
        [dyn] => true
        [dis] => false
    )

[_tag:_type:y\ac\r\Message:private] =>
```

)`

Comment: Could you provide us with the a `print_r` of the `$bigDataArray`?

Comment: @MinistryofChaps We can not access all the data in `$bigDataArray` but only when we access the method provided. Should I provide partial for the `$requiredArray`?

Comment: @BikiTheMe could you not do a `print_r($bigDataArray->getAll())` to display it? If not yes the $requiredArray would be great. Also if you are trying to get the last array of $bigDataArray you can do this: `$lastArray = $bigDataArray[count($bigDataArray) - 1] `

Comment: @MinistryofChaps check the edit with `print_r`

Comment: Does the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an answer here for you:

> The $bigDataArray contains two more arrays but we're interested with the last(3rd) array in it.

To access the last array, you can use the following:

```
$lastArray = $bigDataArray[count($bigDataArray) - 1];
```

This will create a variable with the last array of `$bigDataArray` for you to access.

So if you want to get the fields out of the last array, all you have to do now call `$lastArray['field']`

If I understand your question correctly, here is a sample piece of code I have made to show my point in practice.

```
<?php
$bigDataArray = array();

$array1 = array("field1" => "valueA1", "field2" => "valueA1", "field3" => "valueA1");
$array2 = array("field1" => "valueA2", "field2" => "valueA2", "field3" => "valueA2");
$array3 = array("field1" => "valueA3", "field2" => "valueA3", "field3" => "valueA3");

array_push($bigDataArray, $array1);
array_push($bigDataArray, $array2);
array_push($bigDataArray, $array3);

echo "bigDataArray:";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($bigDataArray);
echo "</pre>";

echo "lastArray:";
echo "<pre>";
$lastArray = $bigDataArray[count($bigDataArray) - 1];
print_r($lastArray);
echo "</pre>";
```